# Binocular Cameras

Tags: lens, camera-settings

I am from India and I would like to know if there is a binocular which uses binocular lenses as camera lenses to take pictures and show pictures live on eyepiece like Military grade binoculars we see in movies.

If yes then are those available in the *regular* market for civilian use ?

Comment: Why? What is your goal, here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about some kind of electronic binoculars, not actually a camera.

Answer (score 3):

> I like to know is there a binocular which uses binocular lenses as camera lenses to take picture

There are binocular cameras like [this Vivitar model](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004MPQYA4) that let you record what you see when looking through the binoculars. There are also adapters for various kinds of cameras that let you take a photo through one of the eyepieces.

> ...and show pictures live on eyepiece like Military grade binoculars we see in movies

What you see in movies is probably about as realistic as a typical Hollywood rendering of any other technology: more caricature than accurate portrayal of reality. It would help to know what film(s) you're thinking of, but a movie portrayal of a binocular view typically has cross-hairs, some sort of superimposed display, and beepy sounds. You're unlikely to find this kind of thing on the market because it doesn't really exist.